# Finding the largest element in a list with K processes using Erlang?

Tags: erlang

It is easy to implement the algorithm using a single process, however, how can I use multiple processes to do the job?

Here is what I have done so far.

```
 find_largest([H], _) -> H;
 find_largest([H, Q | T], R) ->
     if H > Q -> find_largest([H | T], [Q | R]);
       true -> find_largest([Q | T], [H | R])
 end.
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems as if your second argument is unnecessary. You can remove that altogether with no loss of function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given how Erlang represents lists, this is probably not a good idea to try and do in parallel. Partitioning the list implies a lot of copying (since they are linked lists) and so does sending these partitions to other processes. I expect the comparison to be far cheaper than copying everything twice and then combining the results.

The implementation is also not correct, you can find a good one in lists.erl as max/1

```
%% max(L) -> returns the maximum element of the list L

-spec max([T,...]) -> T.

max([H|T]) -> max(T, H).

max([H|T], Max) when H > Max -> max(T, H);
max([_|T], Max)              -> max(T, Max);
max([],    Max)              -> Max.
```

If by some chance your data are already in separate processes, simply get the lists:max/1 or each of the lists and send them to a single place, and then get the lists:max/1 of the result list. You could also do the comparison as you receive the results to avoid building this intermediate list.

Comment: Without trying to prove his code (or even running it), intuitively it does seem correct to me, albeit slightly obfuscated. Please prove me wrong.

Comment: Looking at it now, over a year later, it appears that the version I'm looking at now does return the correct answer for non-empty lists. It does still allocate about 2N lists that don't need to exist (N of them don't even get used!).

Comment: Yes it is not very efficient, but nonetheless should produce the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

The single process version of your code should be replaced by `lists:max/1`. A useful function for parallelizing code is as follows:

```
pmap(Fun, List) ->
    Parent = self(),
    P = fun(Elem) ->
            Ref = make_ref(),
            spawn_link(fun() -> Parent ! {Ref, Fun(Elem)} end),
            Ref
        end,
    Refs = [P(Elem) || Elem <- List],
    lists:map(fun(Ref) -> receive {Ref, Elem} -> Elem end end, Refs).
```

`pmap/2` applies `Fun` to each member of `List` in parallel and collects the results in input order. To use pmap with this problem, you would need to segment your original list into a list of lists and pass that to pmap. e.g. `lists:max(pmap(fun lists:max/1, ListOfLists))`. Of course, the act of segmenting the lists would be more expensive than simply calling `lists:max/1`, so this solution would require that the list be pre-segmented. Even then, it's likely that the overhead of copying the lists outweighs any benefit of parallelization - especially on a single node.

The inherent problem with your situation is that the computation of each sub-task is tiny when compared with the overhead of managing the data. Tasks which are more computationally intensive, (e.g. factoring a list of large numbers), are more easily parallelized.

This isn't to say that finding a max value can't be parallelized, but I believe it would require that your data be pre-segmented or segmented in a way that didn't require iterating over every value.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that pmap is useful for parallelizing "any code", because it certainly wouldn't work in this case. In terms of the map/reduce model pmap can only implement the map phase, not the reduce phase. The question you're answering is a reduction, not a mapping, so the pmap example is confusing at best.

Comment: I agree it was confusing. I edited my original answer to explain how pmap could be used in this case and why it is unlikely to yield a useful parallelization. Thanks for the feedback!